# Install Canon TS3122 drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: printing

Where can I find the drivers for Canon TS3122 and how do I install such drivers. Ubuntu/linus kneb here :)

Comment: They have a `deb` package for your printer it should be pretty easy from there. It involves exacting the files and then running the `deb` command

Comment: Here's a [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/147202) to an answer on how to install a deb package. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit the official [Canon driver download webpage](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/pixma-ts3120-black-wireless-all-in-one-inkjet-printer?tab=drivers_downloads).
2. Download [cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb.tar.gz](http://pdisp01.c-wss.com/gdl/WWUFORedirectTarget.do?id=MDEwMDAwOTEwODAx&cmp=ABR&lang=EN).
3. Open cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb.tar.gz. with the Archive Manager application, and extract the cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb directory.
4. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the *cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb* directory, and then change directories again to the *packages* directory which is located in the cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb directory. There you will find two .deb files, one for 64-bit (cnijfilter2_5.50-1_amd64) and the other one for 32-bit (cnijfilter2_5.50-1_i386). Select the .deb file that matches your OS architecture. In this example it is cnijfilter2_5.50-1_amd64.deb.
5. Install the printer driver.

   ```
   sudo apt install ./cnijfilter2_5.50-1_amd64.deb
   ```